# What is the difference between `su` and `su -` in CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, root, users

I tried to switch to 'root' in CentOS by running `su`. It does change to 'root', but it doesn't seem to be a real 'root' user.

For example, by default, `ifconfig` command in `/sbin` is not found in the path for a normal user, but for 'root', the command can be found. When I run `su`, I still get `bash: ifconfig: command not found` output when I try to run `ifconfig`.

However, when I run `su -`, `ifconfig` just works.

What is the difference between `su` and `su -` in CentOS?

Comment: It's not just CentOS; it's like this on all Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding the `-` option affects your environment behavior.  For all practical purposes, the environment is completely reset.  In general, you likely want to use `su -` instead of plain `su`.  From the man page:

```
 -l      Simulate a full login.  The environment is discarded except for HOME, SHELL, PATH, TERM, and USER.  HOME and SHELL are modified as above.
         USER is set to the target login.  PATH is set to ``/bin:/usr/bin''.  TERM is imported from your current environment.  The invoked shell is
         the target login's, and su will change directory to the target login's home directory.

 -       (no letter) The same as -l.
```

Answer (score 6):

`su -` invokes a login shell, which among other things, ensures that root's `.bashrc` and other shell startup scripts are run, just like as if you'd logged in directly as root via console or SSH.  root's profile usually sets your path to include `/sbin` which is where `ifconfig` generally lives.